# How to programmatically change background color in htop

Tags: terminal, htop

Is there anyway to programmatically change the background color in htop?

When system load reaches a certain threshold, I'd like to change the color from the default black to, say, orange or red, to visually indicate a "warning" or "alarm" status.

I've found ways to change terminal background color using `setterm`, but htop seems to ignore the terminal's settings and use its own colors.

Would it be possible to use some sort of intermediary script to capture htop's output, filter it by replacing the background color, and republish to the terminal? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Basically there isn't such a functionality but you are free to [request the feature](https://github.com/hishamhm/htop/issues) or you can make your hand dirty.. it's opensource.